# Query in Spring data JPA takes too long because of the OR clause

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa

```
@Query("select t1 from Table1 t1 "
+ "where t1.fk_t2 in ( select t3.fk_t2 from Table3 t3"
+ " join t3.fk_t4 t4 where t4.column = ?1 ) "
+ "OR t1.fk_t2.fk_t5.column = ?2 ")                         
Page<T1Entity> findT1Entities(Long param1, Long param2, Pageable pageable);
```

This query takes too long because of the OR clause. I know I can't use UNIONS in Spring data JPA but I somehow need to do it. I would like to do it without calling a SQL procedure or creating a view on database.

Can I do this select with joins?

I think I can do it in two separate query functions but then I need to concatenate them and I don't know what to do with the Pageable object.

How do i take into consideration the page, size when I concatenate into one Page object?

Comment: It would probably help to see your DDLs.  Also, you seem to have two questions.  It is best to spit them into two posts.

Comment: Are you saying that performance is a problem only when the query is executed through Spring Data JPA? Have you tried running the query directly on the database? If the query performance is poor on the database itself, it doesn't matter whether the query is executed through Spring Data JPA or any other means.